# What is a word for a 'product' which has now become a 'part of a product'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Dismantled or deconstructed are options. Both of these have negative connotations. I would prefer a positive or neutral word.

For example:

We bought a big table for our store. In the ledger we marked it as 'in-store'. Then we cut the table in half and sent the two pieces to our factory. Then we marked the table as 'dismantled' in the ledger. Once at the factory we took the two pieces to make two smaller tables. We retuned the two tables to the store and marked them each as 'in-store'.

Any suggestions for a word better than dismantled?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as written. It doesn't even parse.

Comment: I agree with tchrist. "Used parts" is the only thing I can think of that makes sense.

Comment: Would Oreo Cookies being used in McDonalds Oreo McFlurry Milkshakes be an example of the phenomenon?  Or Gorilla Glass being used in the screens of Apple iPhones?

Comment: @jejorda2 your examples are great. Oreo cookies are products, and so is an Oreo McFlurry. Once the Oreo is in a McFlurry it is no longer a true Oreo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possibilities:

salvage, n: (or salvage as a verb) MW:

> something extracted (as from rubbish) as valuable or useful

repurpose, v. (transitive)

> to give a new purpose or use to

So you could say: We salvaged the table from the junk pile, dismantled it, and repurposed the parts.

Comment: Repurpose I think works best for my case. If I could accept, I would.